# Postgres selecting from table row

Tags: postgresql

I have table team which contains
columns like this

```
team_id | name    | competition_id
--------+---------+------
 1      | name 1  | 10
 2      | name 2  | 10
```

and also i have this table fixtures

```
fixture_id  | home_team_id | away_team_id | competition_id
    --------+--------------+--------------+--------------
     1      | 1            | 2            | 10
     2      | 2            | 1            | 10
```

Primary key for table fixtures is fixture_id, home_team_id, away_team_id, 
and competition_id. Also home_team, away_team and competition are foreign keys.

How can I select home_team_name , away_team_name, from fixtures.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I select home_team_name, away_team_name, using join or where clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the `fixtures` table on the `teams` table twice - one for the home team and one for the away team:

```
SELECT  fixture_id, home.name, away.name
FROM    fixtures f
JOIN    teams home on home.team_id = f.home_team_id
JOIN    teams away on away.team_id = f.way_team_id
```